# Is it worth it to gzip js files?

Tags: javascript, performance, gzip

On modern browsers and computers,, is it better to gzip files to save network traffic or to not gzip them which seems like it would save browser CPU?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, [gzip them for transmission](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#GzipCompression), the CPU needed to unzip them is *very* minimal.

Google has [a full writeup here on the benefits](http://code.google.com/speed/articles/use-compression.html).

Comment: what actually does the gzipping?  i wouldn't want anything looking zippy in my http header instpector.  Just curious...

Comment: @Gabriel - the web server you're using usually, Apache, IIS, etc all have this built-in...as do the inspector tools, so you'll see be able to see the content coming down.